# MDI parent size to fit MDI child form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I want the MDI parent to auto-size the child form so it fits inside without scroll bars. Can someone provide some code?

I have used this to differentiate the size of the parent and the child and add it to the size of the parent so I would get a fit. But it's so manual and takes too long to make.

```
void MDICentertoScreen(Form z,Size addedsize)
{
        foreach (Form f in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            f.Close();
        }
        z.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        z.MdiParent = this;

        //  this.Size = Size.Add(z.Size, addedsize);
        this.CenterToScreen();
        z.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this solve your problem:

```
form.MdiParent = this;
form.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;                
form.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you :D Just what I neeeded

Answer (score 4):

Below is what I have used to solve this problem:

1. In the constructor of the child form, you add this line of code:

**this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;**

2. In the Form_Load event, you should add this line of code:

**this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;**

That is, It solves my problem.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use:

```
Form form = new Form();
form.MdiParent = this;
form.Show()
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```